# How do I refund a purchase made through Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store

When I purchase an item from Google Play, I get the following message;

[image]

This message seems to indicate that I can somehow get a refund for my purchase by performing an action on my device within a specified time frame.

What exactly is this message implying I have to do in order to get a refund? How do I refund a purchase made through Google Play?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you open the Play Store on your Android device and go to that app's page within the refund period, a refund option is available to tap. I'm not certain if this is available in the web version of the Play Store (It isn't, as far as I can tell).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

All of the details on refund/cancellations are [here on the Google Play support site](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113515?hl=en):

You can do the following:

- Within 15 minutes, open the google play app and click refund
- Wait 2 hours and don't download the app.  It will auto-cancel
- After 15 minutes, sign into google wallet, select the transaction and contact the seller. They have the option to refund or not at the sellers discretion.

Answer (score 0):

If it has been more than fifteen minutes of purchase, you cannot refund an app via an Android device. [Well, you can but via the desktop version in a browser.]

Go to the Google Play Store, click the gear [settings] icon and select "**My Orders**" You have the option of then requesting for a refund, even if the app was bought a year ago [I've tried].